# Accessing SELECT's computed values in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I’m trying to execute a query like this one:

```
SELECT
  (17 + 4) AS foo,
  foo * 2 AS bar;
```

It fails, returning `Unknown column 'foo' in 'field list'`. So I did this:

```
SELECT
  (@foo := 17 + 4) AS foo,
  @foo * 2 AS bar;
```

Which works. The problem now is that I want to integrate this computed value (`foo`) in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
  (@foo := 17 + 4) AS foo,
  @foo * 2 AS bar
FROM lorem
WHERE foo = 21;
```

Fails: `Unknown column 'foo' in 'where clause'`.

If I replace `foo` with `@foo` in the `WHERE`, it works. But if I replace the literals by a column, it stops working:

```
SELECT
  (@foo := ipsum) AS foo,
  @foo * 2 AS bar
FROM lorem
WHERE @foo = 33;
```

Returns an empty set with this content in table `lorem`:

```
SELECT * FROM lorem;
+-------+
| ipsum |
+-------+
|    33 |
+-------+
```

Comment: Shoudnt foo in WHERE clause be a column?

Comment: Isn't the WHERE clause executed before the select-clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, it works using the `HAVING` clause instead of `WHERE`, like this:

```
SELECT
  (@foo := ipsum * 2) AS foo,
  @foo * 2 AS bar
FROM lorem
HAVING foo = 66;
```

Returns:

```
+------+------+
| foo  | bar  |
+------+------+
|   66 |  132 |
+------+------+
```

With:

```
SELECT * FROM lorem;
+-------+
| ipsum |
+-------+
|    33 |
|    41 |
+-------+
```

Because the `HAVING` is *evaluated* after the `SELECT` one; while the `WHERE` clause is *evaluated* before it and just after the `FROM`.

Answer (score 2):

Subselect!

```
SELECT foo
     , foo * 2 As bar
FROM   (
        SELECT (17 + 4) AS foo
       ) As hey_look_at_me
WHERE  foo = 42
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you want to do this but this will do it.

SELECT
     (@foo := 17 + 4) AS foo,
      @foo:=@foo * 2 AS bar;
   FROM table
   WHERE @foo = 42;

foo is not a column, its a computed value so you cant use it in the where clause. And @foo has value 21 in your query, if you say @foo = 42 it will fail so it wont give any result.

So if you want the final value to be validated then assign it to the variable and validate it.

Comment: I fixed a mistake in my question: it is not `@foo = 42` but `@foo = 21`, it's `bar` that is equal to 42. I edited my question with a new case, slightly different, that doesn't work.

Comment: @KévinLesénéchal.  It works like set, it sets value to a variable and runs the query. But when you assign value from a table, it runs the query first and then assigns bind value. This is why you get value when you assign constant and you dont when you assign from table.                                                              Try SELECT (foo := ipsum) AS foo, foo * 2 AS bar FROM lorem without where filter. You could see value 33 for filter but you cant use it in where clause becuase the value is assigned after running the query with where clause, at that time value of foo is empty.

Comment: So must I compute the value twice? In the `WHERE` clause _and_ in the `SELECT` fields?

Comment: @KévinLesénéchal Why do you need a variable here, why cant you directly use the column. Purpose of set variable is to assign constant value. If you have value in a column, its better to use it directly than assigning to variable. Do all your calculations directly on the column, not on variable.

Comment: The column does not exist in the table, that's why. Sorry if it wasn't clear enough: I have a table which contains the latitude and longitude of the user. This query must calculate the distance with a particular points (represented by the `foo` column), use it to calculate an other column (`bar`) and filter with the `WHERE` to select only users within 25 km of this point.

Comment: Then you can use it directly. You have to do calculation in the inner query and do the where filter in outer query. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/13420

Answer (score -2):

in Oracle SQL i am able to do it simply.
Values in table table_temp

```
select * from table_temp;
foo bar
11  54
17  42


SELECT
  17+4 AS foo,
   foo * 2 AS bar
  from table_temp
  where bar =42;

foo bar
21  42
```

Comment: The question is tagged `MySQL`!

Comment: Even if the question was for Oracle, the answer is wrong.  The condition "bar=42" that's being evaluated in the WHERE clause is based on the physical column `bar` in the table; not the calculated `bar` from SELECT.